React UI component Library created by vite, not working on NextJS 14 (SSR)
I have created a ui library in react with more than 20 components, i have used vite as a bundler.
They are working perfectly fine on client side rendered apps, however when i tried using them on Next14 page, initially they gave an error TypeError: (0, react_WEBPACK IMPORTED MODULE_0_ _• createContext) is not a function at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/-/node_modules/ui-library/dist/bundle.esm.js:2130:78)
at (rsc)/./node modules/ui-library/dist/bundle.esm.js (/Users/himansh/Documents/ssr-uilib-test/ next/serve.
Then i removed all the components and just kept a button and now it is rendering it but without CSS.
as soon as i write 'use client' on top of the component css gets to the button. But i want it like material ui button where it can have css on server as well.
please help! i need to create a UI component library like Material UI, where components can be used in both SSR and CSR apps.
Note: i have tried adding ssr:true in vite as well.
Here is my Vite config:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsConfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path, { resolve } from "path";
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), cssInjectedByJsPlugin(), tsConfigPaths()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@Components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            "@Utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "utils"),
            "@CustomHooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "utils/hooks"),
            "@Assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
            "@Styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "styles"),
            // Add more aliases as needed
        },
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            less: {
                // Less options (e.g., modifying variables)
                javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
        },
    },
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, "./index.ts"),
            name: (format) => `bundle.${format}`,
            fileName: (format) => `bundle.${format}.js`,
            formats: ["esm"],
        },
        outDir: resolve(__dirname, "../../dist"),
        rollupOptions: {
            // Externalize dependencies that are not to be bundled
            // input: resolve(__dirname, "./index.ts"),
            external: ["react", "react-dom"], // React and ReactDOM should be external
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: "React",
                    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});


